# failed to read data from mongob with spark

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, hortonworks-sandbox

I'm working with hdp sandbox 2.6 , spark version 2.2.0 scala version 2.11.8 I want to read data from mongodb with spark in zeppelin netobook so I included longo-spark-connector2_2.11-2.2.0 and mongo-java-driver 3.5.0 in spark2-client/jars when I tried :

```
    import com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark
    import com.mongodb.spark.config.{ReadConfig, WriteConfig}
    import com.mongodb.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import org.bson.Document
    val readConfig = ReadConfig(Map("readPreference.name" -> "secondaryPreferred") ,Some(ReadConfig(Map("uri" -> "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/", "database" -> "test","collection" -> "collections"))))
    val zipDf = spark.sparkSession.read.mongo(readConfig)
```

I got:

```
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 6.0 (TID 27, sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com, executor 1): java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.spark.rdd.partitioner.MongoPartition
at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:82)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream$$anon$1.resolveClass(JavaSerializer.scala:67)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1858)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1744)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2032)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2277)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2059)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1566)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:426)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

any idea and Thanks